# GPU Programming (Parallel Computing) On Android

Tags: android, opencv, parallel-processing, gpu

I have a project that is an image processing app for android devices. For working with image I choose opencv android framework. The whole project consist of some general parts such as blocking the input image, compute dct of each block, sorting the result, compare the feature that get from each block, and finally show some results.

I write this project but it contain so many heavy computing like dct, sorting etc, so I can't even run it on my emulator because it take long time and my laptop shutdown middle of processing. I decided to optimize the processing using parallel computing and gpu programming (it is obvious that some parts like computing dct of blocks can become parallel, but I am not sure about some other parts like sorting), anyway there is a problem that I can't find any straightforward tutorial for doing this.

Here is the question, is there any way to do that or not ? I need it to be global for most of android device not for an especial device !!!

Or beside the gpu programming and parallel computing is there anyway to speed the processing up? (maybe there is other libraries better than opencv!)

Comment: Try Renderscript, but be warned that this is a steep learning curve if you do not already know CUDA or OpenCL.

Comment: i am also stuck at same case. It takes more than 3-4 minutes to process images in android in case of my program. did u find any solution???

Comment: @GarvitaTiwari unfortunately no, I can't find any solution. what I did to handle the problem was change the scenario and using sift as the feature extractor, as it gives fewer keypoints my problem solved.

Comment: @Evil - I am using ORB features, can you tell me which will be better opencl or cuda.. I am making an app for smartphones which may or may not have nvidia gpu

Comment: @GarvitaTiwari sorry, I don't know which one is better. but I suppose choosing Renderscript is much better because google support it. take a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385843/why-did-google-choose-renderscript-instead-of-opencl)

Comment: Thank You, I think this will work for me as well

Comment: @GarvitaTiwari Your welcome, glad to help you.