# Opencl on android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, opencl, renderscript

My android project is about visual feature extraction
In order to reduce keypoint detection and feature extraction time ; I think that GPU computing is may be a solution.
I want to test OpenCl or renderscript functions on Android emulator . 
Is that feasible?

Answer (score 4):

RenderScript should be available in the emulator since 4.0.4 version (Ice Cream Sandwich) with GPU setting enabled. Any support for OpenCL would be outside of any official Android/Google channels, see: [Why did Google choose RenderScript instead of OpenCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385843/why-did-google-choose-renderscript-instead-of-opencl)